# Pyspark Pandas-Vectorized UDFs

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, user-defined-functions, pandas-udf

I am trying to convert this udf into this pandas udf, in order to avoid creating two pandas udfs.

Convert this:

```
@udf("string")
  def splitEmailUDF(email: str, position: int) -> str:
  return email.split("@")[position]
```

into this in one pandas udf --- position ??? Datatype or something else!

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
    
@pandas_udf("string")
def splitEmailUDFVec(email: pd.Series, position: ???????) -> pd.Series:
  return email.str.split("@").str[position]
```

Of course I can always create two pandas_udfs:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
        
@pandas_udf("string")
def splitFirstNameUDFVec(email: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  return email.str.split("@").str[0]
        
@pandas_udf("string")
def splitDomainUDFVec(email: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  return email.str.split("@").str[1]
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup

```
df.show()

+------------+
|       email|
+------------+
| foo@bar.com|
|baz@spam.com|
+------------+
```

Define a wrapper function which takes email and pos as arguments and returns the underlying pandas udf function

```
def split(email, pos):
    @F.pandas_udf('string')
    def _split(email: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        return email.str.split('@').str[pos]
    
    return _split(email)

df = df.withColumn('firstname', split('email', 1))
```

Result

```
df.show()

+------------+--------+
|       email|  domain|
+------------+--------+
| foo@bar.com| bar.com|
|baz@spam.com|spam.com|
+------------+--------+
```

---

Alternatively a better/efficient approach is to use regex extraction if your goal is to only split the email address into its name and domain components.

```
f = lambda n: F.regexp_extract('email', '(.*)@(.*)', n)
df = df.select('*', f(1).alias('firstname'), f(2).alias('domain'))
```

Result

```
df.show()

+------------+---------+--------+
|       email|firstname|  domain|
+------------+---------+--------+
| foo@bar.com|      foo| bar.com|
|baz@spam.com|      baz|spam.com|
+------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi Shubham Sharma, not only you showed me how to work with pandas_udfs but also show me alternative and efficient way to do the same. I am currently learning udfs and now you have taught me more. Thanks